# Pymongo aggregate does not return a cursor but an object

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am writing a code using pymongo which uses the aggregation framework to save some data in other collection.
The code is this:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

def makeAggregate():
  print 'Making aggregation of commits..'

  commitsCollection = MongoClient("mongo-srv", 27017).gt.commits
  rankingCollection = MongoClient("mongo-srv", 27017).gt.commitsRanking

  pipe = [{'$unwind': '$commits'},{'$group':{"_id":"$_id", "picture": {"$first": "$picture"},'a':{'$sum':'$commits.a'},'d':{'$sum':'$commits.d'},'c':{'$sum':'$commits.c'}}}]
  cursor = commitsCollection.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)

  obj = next(cursor, None)
  while obj:
    rankingCollection.save(obj)
    obj = next(cursor, None)

makeAggregate()
```

The code works fine on my computer, but when I moved the script to a server, then the script failed, saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aggregate.py", line 17, in <module>
    makeAggregate()
  File "aggregate.py", line 12, in makeAggregate
    obj = next(cursor, None)
TypeError: dict object is not an iterator
```

The command `python --version` returns

On my computer:
`Python 2.7.3`

On the server
`Python 2.7.6`

The command `pip show pymongo` returns

On my computer:

```
Usage: pip COMMAND [OPTIONS]
pip: error: No command by the name pip show
  (maybe you meant "pip install show")
```

(Executed `pip install show` but keeps saying this when running show..)

On the server:

```
Name: pymongo
Version: 2.7
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pymongo-2.7-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
Requires:
```

Running `pymongo.version` inside python gives me:

In my computer:
`3.0`

In the server
`2.7`

Maybe I have to update this? How can I do that?

Comment: Can you give version of Pymongo, MongoDB for Local and Server machine.

Comment: @imagin I wrote what `python --version` gives and the mongo server being used is the same in both cases. Are you asking for something else maybe?

Comment: Yes the PyMongo and MongoDB version

Comment: Can you please try following to check what version of pymongo python actually looking at `import pymongo` followed by `pymongo.version` ? You can run this on python command line as well for both local machine and server.

Comment: @Satarangi_Re just updated the post with the versions, the problem might be there as my version is 3.0 and the server's is 2.7. Maybe I have to update it? How to I do that?

Comment: Can you try following instructions given here : http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/installation.html depending on OS of your server

Comment: @Satarangi_Re thanks. that did it. so the problem was that in version previous to 3.0 the aggregate framework returned the object directly and not a cursor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes thats the issue, 
 Different version of Pymongo for Development and Production environment

In *PyMongo 2.7* it returns : **Dictionary**

```
{u'ok': 1.0, u'result': [{u'count': 3, u'_id': u'cat'}, {u'count': 2, u'_id': u'dog'}, {u'count': 1, u'_id': u'mouse'}]}
```

Whereas in *PyMongo 3.0* it returns : **Cursor Object**

```
{u'count': 3, u'_id': u'cat'}, {u'count': 2, u'_id': u'dog'}, {u'count': 1, u'_id': u'mouse'}
```

[Refer Pymongo 2.7 Documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/2.7rc0/examples/aggregation.html)
 [Refer Pymongo 3.0 Documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/examples/aggregation.html)
 [Changes made from PyMongo 2.7 to PyMongo 3.0](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate)

**Pro-Tip :**
Use Virtual Environment for Python and create a Requirements Text File.So as you can install the same version of Python Library and it Dependencies in Local Development and in Production.

[Refer Virtual Environment Python Package](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thanks ! Nice pro-tip btw !!